# Can't import database through terminal

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import database through terminal but nothing happens. Literally. No errors just -

```
root@toma-hp-zbook-17:/var/www/html/elite-core# mysql -u root -p elite-core < elite-core.sql 
Enter password: 
root@toma-hp-zbook-17:/var/www/html/elite-core#
```

I've created database before the script.What am I doing wrong or where should I look for errors if one ? I am absolutely newbie about linux. Thank you!

**EDIT**
I tried to import from the graphic interface and I get this :

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/display_import.lib.php#371: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Import',
array,
)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#456: PMA_getHtmlForImportOptionsFormat(array)
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#691: PMA_getHtmlForImport(
string '5b9bf81772509',
string 'database',
string 'elite-core',
string '',
integer 2097152,
array,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
)
./db_import.php#43: PMA_getImportDisplay(
string 'database',
string 'elite-core',
string '',
integer 2097152,
)
```

Where can I find the `plugin_interface.lib` ? Tried with `find ~ -name '*plugin_interface'` but no files were found.

Comment: When `mysql` doesn't complain then usually it had no reason to do so and I would assume **the import worked**. Can you check that?

Comment: The database is empty :/ Checked and tried few times. Can I some find kind of `error.log` or something ? Or maybe it is some problem with my configuration.

Comment: Ok. I found something. When I tried to import from the graphic interface. Will edit the question.